# How to get the selected row value in aspxgridview

Tags: devexpress

I have a aspxgridview and use the popup edit form. In the gridview there is a column "Unitname". In the popup edit forms header I would like to show this Unit name  of the currently edited row.

i am using StartRowEditing event is used to show this.

also I want to get the Unitname and it should stored into string.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The selected row values can be accessed both in the server-side code and in the browser.

To access selected values on the server side, use the [GetSelectedFieldValues](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridBase_GetSelectedFieldValuestopic) method of the ASPxGridView. It returns the list of values corresponding to field names passed as method parameters.

On the client side, the ASPxGridView is presented by the ASPxClientGridView component. It provides a similar method to obtain selected values: [GetSelectedFieldValues](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebScriptsASPxClientGridView_GetSelectedFieldValuestopic).